# Property '$refs' does not exist on type 'Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, refs

I have a child component

```
 <student-list
   ref="studentList"
   :all-students="allStudent"
                    
 />
```

What I like to do is gab the html from this list and reuse it

```
const studentInformation = this.$refs.studentList.$refs[id][0].$el.outerHTML
```

This works fine until making the component TS, I get the error

**Property '$refs' does not exist on type 'Vue**

I tried any

```
  const studentInformation: any =  this.$refs.studentList.$refs[id][0].$el.outerHTML

    |                                                             ^^^^^
```

html element

```
const studentInformation: any =  this.$refs.studentList.$refs[id][0].$el.outerHTML as HTMLElement
```

and vue

const studentInformation: any =  (this.$refs.studentList.$refs as Vue)[id][0].$el.outerHTML as HTMLElement

Any help would be appreciated I am using the options api.